# matplotlib not using matplotlibrc file in IPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I recently upgraded from matplotlib v1.5.3 from v2.0.0, but with this change, it seems that matplotlib no longer uses my edited matplotlibrc file when plotting figures. When I open the matplotlibrc file, I see that my changes are in fact implemented, but when I type `matplotlib.rcParams`, these changes are not displayed. Thinking that maybe it was looking at a different matplotlibrc file, I ran `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`, but this points to the same directory of my edited matplotlibrc file.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

FYI, I am running matplotlib 2.0.0 in Python 2.7.12 with IPython 5.1.0. To open matplotlib in IPython, I utilize first the command `%matplotlib`.

Comment: ask matplotlib authors.

Comment: Can you try to load it specifically using ``matplotlib.rc_params_from_file``? What happens then?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that the matplotlibrc *was* working, then iPython was [overriding it](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11815) at the end of the cell. The way to check for this is to import matplotlib and print the `plt.rcParams`  dict in the same cell, then run the same cell again. If it changes between calls, iPython is overriding it.

The fix is to add

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
c.InlineBackend.rc = {}
```

to your `ipython_config.py`. The second line tells iPython not to update the rParams dict.

Answer (score 1):

In matplotlib 2.0.0, the default location on Linux for the `matplotlibrc` file has moved from

```
~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc
```

to

```
~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
```

Try moving your customised file to there and see if it works. That worked for me when I moved from 1.5.3 to 2.0.0.

See the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) for more info on how it finds the right matplotlibrc file.