# Custom matplotlibrc file does not load correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am running the latest versions of Python (3.5.2), IPython (6.1.0), and Jupyter (--version says 4.3.0 and pip3 shows 5.1.0) on Ubuntu.

Here is a quick example that illustrates the issue that appears in Jupyter. I changed the default `figure.figsize` in the matplotlibrc file.

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
print(matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'])
```

> $USER/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
>
> [24.0, 13.5]

But as soon as I import the `pyplot` submodule, the parameters change back to default:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
print(matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'])
```

> $USER/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
>
> [6.0, 4.0]

Why is this happening and how can I use custom params together with `plt`?

My question might be similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862315/matplotlib-not-using-matplotlibrc-file-in-ipython) that was not resolved.

Comment: A question in the same direction with a more condensed answer, but focussing on the background instead of the figure size would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656668/matplotlibrc-rcparams-modified-for-jupyter-inline-plots).

Comment: Thanks, all those links helped!