# Permanently changing the margins in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, margins

The default xmargins and ymargins for matplotlib are 0.05. I wanted to permanently change these to zero.

So I went to the matplotlib rc file (https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlibrc-sample) on my PC and changed the `axes.xmargin` and `axes.ymargin` to 0. I found the path of this file by typing in `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`.

I typed in `print(matplotlib.rcParams["axes.xmargin"])` in to the jupyter notebook and this returns 0.05 so the changes clearly haven't been made. Even when I simply type this in to the command line after loading python the margins haven't changed.

But I've manually changed it. Here is a screenshot of how I edited the file:[image]

As you can see, the axes are both set to zero.

I have typed `conda install matplotlib` in to the command line to see if this would change anything, but nothing's changed.

Comment: You apparently edited the wrong file. See [the-matplotlibrc-file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) for how to find out which file to edit.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I loaded python in my command window, import matplotlib and then entered ```matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()```. I then altered this file?

Comment: Check if when in jupyter notebook this path is different

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It is the same path.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Did you reload the kernel after making the changes? It could also mean that you have some other code that sets the setting back. You can check `print(matplotlib.rcParams["axes.xmargin"])` to see if it is applied.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I restarted the kernel yes. I have ran that command and it returns 0.05, so clearly it hasn't been applied. But when I check the file myself at the given path the axes.xmargin and axes.ymargin are set to 0?

Comment: You may have made a mistake editing the file though. It would help showing screenshots of your edit and your attempts.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I mean, all I did was change 0.05 to 0 in both instances? Is this correct?

Comment: I think this is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862315/matplotlib-not-using-matplotlibrc-file-in-ipython

Comment: I don't think so. What about my suggestion with the screenshots?

Comment: What is it you want a screenshot of? The edited file?

Comment: Everything that can help finding out where this goes wrong. So the edited file and the jupyter notebook where you test it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited my post

Comment: I see. You forgot to uncomment the lines. (i.e. remove the `#`)

Comment: Ah I see! Do I just have to uncomment the lines I modified or?

Comment: Of course you can uncomment all lines, but that won't change anything because they show the defaults anyways. So I would just uncomment those where you want to change the defaults.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!